# How Linux differs from other scripting languages?

Tags: linux

I am interested to acquire a small amount of intermediate knowledge in Linux, I would like to learn to write scripts using Linux operation, I am preparing for Red-Hat Certification sometime next year. How does it differ from other web-scripting languages such as Php, Ruby? Furthermore, can you direct me to some links on how to write Linux?.

Comment: You should review where you get your understanding from regarding "Linux is coded in putty shell scripting" and that source of information. Whatever it might mean it seems to be incorrect. Questions about learning material are anyway [off-topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this Q&A site.

Comment: What I meant was Linux scripting IDE is putty.

Comment: Except, it isn't.

Comment: To be clear, Linux is a kernel (a low-level part of an operating system), not a scripting language. Additionally, no part of Linux itself is actually written in a scripting language—it's all C. You're probably thinking of shell scripting languages (which are still, for the most part, unrelated to putty).

Comment: To me your question is clear... that you don't understand Operating systems and that you are very anxious to learn, and have gotten started by logging into a Linux environment from Windows.  The tool you used "putty" is a console for assessing the computer and typing in commands which will give you basically what you get when you run "cmd" (the command console in Windows).  The default prompt you get is called a "bash" shell.  You can write script commands there (script.sh) similar to writing a "script.bat" in windows with much more features... (out of comment text answers are deactivated).

Comment: Hi L.D yes I am very anxious to learn how this works, could you post some links where to start including writing scripts.

Comment: @Chris If you use "@" and my userID to respond to my comment (as the first word) I'll be notified of the update.  [Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-variables.htm), [Bash Programming](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html), [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=bash+scripting+tutorial+for+beginners)

Comment: @L.D copy, I'll look into this.

Comment: Chris.  Please notice the "hold" comment suggesting that you clarify your question.  You can actually click on "edit" in your question to make it clear that you're tying to **use** the Linux Operation and write scripting Language.  There are a number of scripting Languages that can fit the bill if you will fix your question.  You've made it clear what you want by your comments, now try to do the same with your question by editing it so that you can get better answers.

Comment: @L.D appreciate it.

Comment: @Chris I don't understand why they have not taken your question of hold.  The content of your comments and as well as the re-write of the context of your question should be very clear.  It might be that you mistakenly wrote `Linux` rather than writing **Using** `Linux`.  If you would correct this in your subject they may take your question off hold and remove some of those down-votes.  Of course, it was always very clear to me.  But it needs to be clear to everybody.  After you start getting good input with your question, you'll find this to be a great resource for your programming quest.

Comment: @Chris I added the single word to make your question clearer.  I may not have enough reputation points for my edit to stick.  But since it's your question, you it might stick if you perform the change.  Since you have already verified this is what you are saying.

Comment: @HalosGhost Actually I understand what the user is saying.  I programmed my Linux machines for many users using putty (from Windows).  I didn't initially know how to explain in the best Jargon what I was doing (and still have gaps).  But I remember where I came from and clearly understand the user's question and every comment he has made.  Technically putty (as you say) isn't an IDE.  The user is meaning programming environment when he uses the word IDE.  And again, you can program your Linux machine using the putty tool.

Comment: @L.D.James, I have no idea why you're pinging me about this. As far as I'm concerned, this question is fundamentally based on faulty assumptions and still holds not enough information to answer adequately. For example, _what_ language is the OP wanting to program in? Shell? C? etc. Regardless, the matter seems to be settled.

Comment: @HalosGhost the user has clearly said he wanted to program in script.  He gave examples.  He asked how is programming in Linux different.  Actually the answer to his very good question is that it isn't different.  There might be better answers than the one I just provided in this comment.  But as far as I can see his question is legitimate.  I can understand if it goes beyond the scope to give suggestions in programming or picking out the best scripting Language.  But the user asked how is it different.  The answer is that it isn't.  Was acknowledging your comment with the ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is a whole operating system, just like Windows. You usually use a shell like bash to run any commands on it. If you want to connect from a Windows box to a remote linux box you can use putty.

But those are very different things. You run putty on your local windows box. It will connect to the remote linux box and present you a shell which allows you to issue commands on that box.

The "scripting language" you are referring to is probably that bash shell. But bash is not linux specific. You can have bash for windows, too. For example if you install [git](http://git-scm.com/) it also gives you a really nice bash called git-bash, which allows you exactly the same type of "scripting" as on linux.

Also be aware that there are no real "web-scripiting languages". Bash is never used for serving web sites. Ruby is not the same as "ruby on rails" and even for php it is perfectly possible to write applications that do nothing web related at all.

Comment: Why the -1? Is there any problem with this answer?

Comment: Great answer.  I see you understood the user's question.  You probably got down votes because some people don't have a lot of tolerance for people novice questions, and coincidentally associated your answer with the way the question was initially worded.  For me, it was always clear that the user was trying to come into using the Linux OS for programming, and it appears that you answered what he was asked, which appears to be a good question... just worded a little too novice.  I'm up-voting your answer which should have helped others to understand the question better.